# How to create a cumulative posts and members count

Tags: posts, array, statistics, registered

I need to show my users cumulative posts and members registered count by date.
It has to be displayed in an array format like this

**for posts**

```
array(array(2011,08,02), 500)
array(array(2011,08,03), 520)
array(array(2011,08,04), 540)
array(array(2011,08,05), 560)
array(array(2011,08,06), 580)
```

the same case for members

iam using wordpress.com stats to for statistics, i cant figure out how to do this, could anyone help me...

Comment: Why in that format? Are you importing this data into another system? When you say users cumulative posts do you mean you want data per user or all the users combined? Do you want to exclude admin posts?

Comment: @brady i need cumulative posts per date, regardless of the user, like today- 200, yesterday-180 ..... in an array format so that i can form a graph based on that.

Comment: do you need it as a one off script or as a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very crude script I've knocked up to get what you are after:

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');

$posts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&order=ASC');

$posts_times = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post_time = strtotime($post->post_date);
    $offset = $post_time % (60*60*24);
    $post_time -= $offset;
    $posts_times[$post_time]++;
}

$keys = array_keys($posts_times);

$running_count = 0;

$end_data = array();

for($i = $keys[0]; $i <= $keys[(count($keys)-1)]; $i += (60*60*24)) {
    $running_count += $posts_times[$i];
    $end_data[] = array(
        array(date("Y", $i), date("m", $i), date("d", $i)),
        $running_count
    );
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($end_data);
?>
```